# How to split the file with following delimiter in Python, tried custom delimiter '\x01' but it is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, delimiter

Trying to split the data, in csv file, that has the below format

[image]

[image]

Tried the below code; it just gives a single column list

```
import csv
class custom_sep:
    delimiter = chr(0x01) # or delimiter = '\x01'
csv.register_dialect("custom_sep", custom_sep)

with open(file_path, 'r',encoding="UTF-8") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,dialect="custom_sep")
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

It just gives a single column list instead of separate columns

Comment: Also you could just try `csv.reader(f, delimiter="\x01")`. And it would be helpful if you uploaded a small part of your csv file.

Comment: how do you know those boxes indicate ASCII character 1?  I'd suggest reading the first line of the file and add the `repr` of it to the question...

Comment: If you're on Linux, run `head -1 file.csv | hhd` to see the first line with its hex representation, and show us the results. This is probably equivalent to what @SamMason is suggested with `repr()` of the first line, it'll give you a hex dump so we can know for sure what you need to split on.

Comment: I don't think your call to `csv.register_dialect()` is valid.  The second parameter is supposed to be a subclass of `csv.Dialect`.

Comment: your code works fine on a file created by `echo test\01test2\01t3 > test.csv` . So similar to others, I'd suggest checking some of the lines of your csv file in hex.

`$ python3 test.py`
`['test', 'test2', 't3']`

Comment: that image of the file doesn't help!  you need a hex dump of the file.  I presume you're under windows, if so the following might help: https://superuser.com/q/468456

Comment: @SamMason ya I am using windows, does viewing notepad+ works, I could see 'SOH' in it

Comment: @boris is it possible to add csv file here?

Comment: @jasonharper it works when I just test it for , as a custom delimiter

Comment: the output of `print(repr(open(file_path).readline()))` would help a lot...

Comment: @SamMason that gives me this '"title\x01""description""\x01""category""\x01""sub_cat""\x01""sub_sub_cat""\x01""gender""",,,\n'

Comment: What about the repr of the second line of the csv?

Comment: the reason the `csv` module is failing to parse that is because the delimiter is "inside" the quotes, rather than after.  also all the extra quotes later on make the file look very strange, the extra commas at the end look equally suspicious.  where did it come from? can you get a more standard formatted file?

Comment: @SamMason ya noticed, but ignored, thanks for pointing it out. this is a task I have to do clean up and infer. Earlier I tried to replace all the double quotes with empty character but not as it has columns with empty data that has double quotes

Comment: @Boris When I print further lines it just prints junk chars

Comment: Any other idea guys of how can I proceed further?

Comment: maybe you could go back to an older version of the file?  note this is going way off topic for stackoverflow...

Comment: @eswaraamirthans your csv file is pretty broken. Looks like the "separators" are sometimes `\x01` or `"\x01"` (with extra quotes) or like `"\x01""`, followed by 3 useless commas in the header. You should talk to whoever gave you this junk and ask them to fix their software. You could also manually edit the csv to make it easier to parse, starting with deleting the 3 commas on the first line and then stripping the useless `"` from the lines as you parse them.

Comment: @SamMason I just tested a sample with '\x01' in double-quotes, it is not working.

Comment: @Boris ya double quotes is the root cause for this issue, I may have to do some clean up activity, thank you guys.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the first 3 or so rows of your CSV as text, that way we can copy/paste it and test with it. Alternatively, use a service like pastebin to include a link to an actual file.

Comment: @MartinEvans It's a good idea, I would do that.